# Notice: Undefined index

Tags: 8

I copy the site files to my local testing environment(win7, not linux os). The site cannot run normaly. The error notes show below:

```
Notice: Undefined index: sidebar_first in include() (Line 138 of C:\xampp\htdocs\web\modules\system\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: sidebar_second in include() (Line 144 of C:\xampp\htdocs\web\modules\system\page.tpl.php).
Warning: file_put_contents(temporary://fil5572.tmp): failed to open stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in file_unmanaged_save_data() (Line 1938 of C:\xampp\htdocs\web\includes\file.inc).
cannot be created.
Warning: file_put_contents(temporary://fil55A2.tmp): failed to open stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in file_unmanaged_save_data() (Line 1938 of C:\xampp\htdocs\web\includes\file.inc).
cannot be created.
Warning: file_put_contents(temporary://fil55B2.tmp): failed to open stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in file_unmanaged_save_data() (Line 1938 of C:\xampp\htdocs\web\includes\file.inc).
cannot be created.
Warning: file_put_contents(temporary://fil55C3.tmp): failed to open stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in file_unmanaged_save_data() (Line 1938 of C:\xampp\htdocs\web\includes\file.inc).cannot be created.
Warning: file_put_contents(temporary://fil55E3.tmp): failed to open stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in file_unmanaged_save_data() (Line 1938 of C:\xampp\htdocs\web\includes\file.inc). cannot be created.
Warning: file_put_contents(temporary://fil55E4.tmp): failed to open stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in file_unmanaged_save_data() (Line 1938 of C:\xampp\htdocs\web\includes\file.inc).cannot be created.
```

I need your help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably a problem with settings for the temporary directory, which is a typical issue moving from Linux OS to Windows or vice versa (this goes for the warning messages that you described)

You should go to: admin/config/media/file-system and set the temporary directory correctly for your local system.

The first two messages are PHP notices which are not critical, but indicating that there is a minor issue within your template files not correctly verifying variables. This is something that would normally be suppresed in a production environment and therefore you might not see this on your other server but it is there too.

By the way: I doubt that you are using Drupal 8 as you are indicating in tags, because page.tpl.php is something that clearly points to Drupal 7.